# Proper way to define a Migration yaml?

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to do a POC using Migrate, Migrate Plus, and Migrate Tools to define migrations and having trouble getting my migration to register and appear in the list of migrations for the migration group I created (in the UI).

In my yaml file, I put in the basics just to try and get it to appear in the UI:

```
id: remote_entity
label: TESTING
migration_group: mygroup
```

I named the file `remote_entity.yml` in a folder called `migrations` (I got this from the example in the Migrate Plus) module. Yet, it does not appear.

I see other modules have theirs in the `config/install` directory with a naming pattern assigned. Where is this file supposed to really be? What should it be named to get picked up? If it is in the `config/install` directory, do I have to uninstall/install the module numerous times as I iterate over a POC and make changes to the migration definition?

Comment: You have to prefix name like migrate_plus.migration.id_name.yml

Comment: Where? In an install folder? In a migrations folder? Having trouble finding docs on this.

Comment: You can follow structure folder, file name of module **migrate_example**(sub module of module **migrate_plus**). Group migrate have syntax name **migrate_plus.migration_group.group_id.yml, Migrate have syntax name **migrate_plus.migration.migrate_id.yml**. So you need to create migrate group firstly, and create migrate and reinstall module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is this file supposed to really be?

It's config, so config/install is fine

> What should it be named to get picked up?

Like other config it's module_name.type.machine_name.yml, so (e.g.) migrate_plus.migration.id.yml

> do I have to uninstall/install the module numerous times as I iterate over a POC and make changes to the migration definition?

No, just like a normal config import you can do it partially:

```
drush cim --partial --source=/path/to/your/module/config/install
```

---

I did exactly what you did when I first played with Migrate Plus - tried to put the config in a `migrations` folder, like the example, but it didn't work for me either.

As migrations are config, this does make sense looking back - otherwise Migrate Plus would need to do something non-standard when discovering/importing migration configurations.

Comment: Let me give this a shot.

Comment: So the file(s) are recognized now, but the cim partial command does not seem to work for changing a yaml file here.

Comment: Uninstalling also does not delete config objects, so re-installing does not overwrite with changes.

Comment: @Kevin I just finished a project which was heavy on migration - I must’ve used the partial flag 100+ times a day, it never failed to work for me. IIRC I had trouble getting it to work properly on Acquia though

Comment: Oh that one’s easy - add the module as a dependency of each migration config. Then they get nuked when the module is uninstalled

Comment: I feel like I’m about 2 months ahead of your pain, I came up against literally every one of these problems too

Comment: I'm just used to the old way where you extend a MigrateBase class and voila there it is.

Comment: Yeah, the new way is more flexible but definitely a bit perplexing to start with; the docs aren’t amazing, I think I used other modules as a guide (I think maybe Webform and other usual suspects), the examples with migrate_plus didn’t get me that far because they lacked explanation/context

Comment: DAMN! Ok, now I see what you are saying. This stuff should be documented better upfront, otherwise it makes iterating into it difficult.